# Is the normal bundle invariant under homotopy?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, symplectic-geometry

Let $(M^{2n},J)$ be a complex $n$-manifold and $u:\mathbb{CP}^1\to M$ an immersed $J$-holomorphic curve. Then there exists a short exact sequence of vector bundles $$0\to T\mathbb{CP}^1\to u^{\ast}TM\to N_u\to 0$$ which defines the normal bundle $N_u$ of $u$. By Grothendieck's theorem, $$N_u=\bigoplus_{i=1}^{n-1}\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{CP}^1}(a_i)$$ where $$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}a_i=c_1(u^{\ast}TM)-2. \qquad \qquad\qquad (\star)$$

**Question:** Suppose $v:\mathbb{CP}^1\to M$ is another $J$-holomorphic curve which is homotopic to $u$ and let $b_1,\dots,b_{n-1}$ be the defined by $$N_v=\bigoplus_{i=1}^{n-1}\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{CP}^1}(b_i).$$ Is it true that $b_i=a_i$ for all $i=1,\dots,n-1$?

**Comments:** Note that the answer is "yes" in the case $n=2$, since then there is only one unknown $a_1$ and $(\star)$ gives $a_1=c_1(u^{\ast}TM)-2$. I'n not sure if this is true in higher dimensions. Perhaps a counterexample can be constructed when $\pi_2(M)=0$ and all such curves are homotopic, e.g. $M=\mathbb{C}^3$. The question is essentially how the normal bundle can change within a given homotopy class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not true. For instance, for lines on a smooth cubic threefold, generically the normal bundle is $O \oplus O$, but for some lines it is $O(1) \oplus O(-1)$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please suggest a reference? Also, are there special cases for $n=3$ when the answer is "yes"?

Comment: For example, it is true for the class of lines in $M=\mathbb{CP}^3$ with the standard complex structure.

Comment: @rpf: See Kuznetsov, Alexander G.; Prokhorov, Yuri G.; Shramov, Constantin A. Hilbert schemes of lines and conics and automorphism groups of Fano threefolds. Jpn. J. Math. 13 (2018), no. 1, 109--185 and references therein. Typically, the normal bundle of lines is "uniform", when the Hilbert scheme of lines is homogeneous under some group action. This covers the case of $P^3$.